# SED substitutions: use the original pattern in the substitution part

Tags: sed, regular-expression

How can I use `sed` to match the search 'pattern' and reuse it again in the 'substitution' part?

Example: I want  the command:

```
echo "12a34" | sed 's/a/#bcd/g'
```

to return

```
12abcd34
```

What should be the `#` parameter to get the right substitution?

Comment: If you mean all *pattern* in `s/pattern/substitusion/` you can recall by `&` symbol. Thats mean `sed 's/a/&bcd/g'`. If you'l need just part of pattern you can use *back refference*: `sed 's/\(a\)3/\1bcd/g'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already commented, the solution is to take the `&` character in the substitution part:

```
echo "12a34" | sed 's/a/&bcd/g'
```

Like this the `&` is just replaced by the `a` in the search pattern.